# Run time error "5981" Could not open macro storage

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm getting this error message: "Run-time error 5981. Could not open macro Storage" This happens when I'm creating a new Word document using a template. The code is posted below. When we run this macro. It create a new document but it shows the error. Please help where i am doing wrong.

```
Sub AddTemplate1()

Documents.Add Template:="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\Letter_Portrait_Template_CONFIDENTIAL.dotx"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this error.

After weeks of searching the internet, tried everything what was suggested: Setting authorization, renewed my Normal.dotm etc etc.

I finally solved the problem by changing the compatibility - mode from 'windows xp' to its normal mode (windows 10 in my case) for the (yes outdated) VB6.exe